# Dynamic AngularJS Forms

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got a view in which lies the following `<div>`

```
<div ng-repeat="product in Product_List" ng-show="Product_List.length >=1">

 <input type="text" ng-model="product.ProductCode" ng-value="CurrentProduct.ProductCode">
 <input type="text" ng-model="product.ProductName" ng-value="CurrentProduct.ProductName">

</div>
```

Now push to the `Product_List` array, resulting in having the elements above repeated as follows,

```
$scope.Product_List.push({
    "ProductCode": "",
    "ProductName": ""
});
```

So far so good, but following is my problem,

How do i make an array as follows every time i add elements to the `Product_List` ?

```
[
{
 "ProductCode" :"P1",
 "ProductName" :"Coffee"
},
{
 "ProductCode" : "P2",
 "ProductName" : "Beer"
}
]
```

Comment: Push those values instead of empty string...

Comment: Oh well, that was an example, i want to push what ever the user types in the ng-models into that array. Keeping in mind that the user can add an unlimited number of `product.ProductCode` and `product.ProductName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same product object for current value it will update the object value. http://jsfiddle.net/sudeep1049/jbj4movu/

```
<input type="text" ng-model="product.ProductCode" >
<input type="text" ng-model="product.ProductName">
```